# Optimization With Few Measurements?

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

In the context of Statistics and Probability, we are often told it is not advisable to:

- If you have an independent variable with many categories (e.g. there are 41,683 ZIP codes in the USA - if you data on people from many ZIP codes and you decide to use the ZIP code they are located in as an independent variable), do not include this variable into a regression model (e.g. salary = bo + b1*age + b2*gender + b3*ZIPCODE)

I always wondered if there was a mathematical reason for this.

I have usually been told that the problem with this is the following: suppose your dataset is only 100,000 rows - this means that you will inevitably have very few rows for some of the ZIP codes. As a result, you will end up generalizing your results based on very few observations to the entire ZIP code. Therefore, it is better not to use this variable as a independent variable in your model.

But is there a mathematical reason for this as well? When writing the Maximum Likelihood Equations and attempting to optimize them in such a context (i.e. when you have decided to use the ZIP code as an independent variable) - are there any mathematical problems that may arise when attempting to optimize a system of equations a variable only has a few observations per group?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Zip codes should be considered about as random and unordered as first names.
Any correlation is more or less coincidental.

Actually, with first names, some correlation can be expected, since it also could relate to gender, age, and ethnicity. However, without a proper ordering of the first names, this relation is coincidental and not linear.